# gcloud beta run configurations update: command not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I have been following this [article](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions) to configure Endpoints for functions.

I am stuck at the following command

```
gcloud beta run configurations update \
   --service CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME  \
   --set-env-vars ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME=YOUR_SERVICE_NAME \
   --project ESP_PROJECT_ID
```

which is mentioned in the article as I am getting error

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.configurations) Invalid choice: 'update'.

I have tried to do `gcloud components update` as well but nothing seems to work.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the documentation is not upto date.

New command is following

```
gcloud beta run services update \
   CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME  \
   --set-env-vars ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME=YOUR_SERVICE_NAME \
   --project ESP_PROJECT_ID
```